# Mock autowired generic interface

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock the autowired interface `itemRepository` using `@MockBean`, but I have a `NullPointerExcepption` when running the test when the test performs the `itemRepository.findAll()` method in `ResourceController.listAll()`. At breaking point the test before the call `resourceControler.listAll()`, my mock `itemRepository` is correctly created, but inside `listAll()`, the mock is not referenced.

Have you an idea how can I mock this kind of autowired generic interface?

The methode to test listAll():

```
    public abstract class ResourceController<T extends RESTResource<T>> extends MainController {

        @Autowired
        protected RESTRepository<T> itemRepository;

        public Page<T> listAll(T search, Pageable pageable) {
            return itemRepository.findAll(search, pageable);
        }
    }
```

The generic interface:

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface RESTRepository<T> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, 
    String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    }
```

FindAll() method is a public method implemented by spring SimpleJpaRepository. I can't remove the annotation @NoRepositoryBean, but even removing, the mock remain null.

The test:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration
    public class ResourceControllerTest {



        @MockBean(classes = ResourceController.class, answer = CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
        private  ResourceController ressourceControler;

        @MockBean(classes = RESTResource.class)
        private  RESTResource search;

        @MockBean
        protected RESTRepository itemRepository;

        @MockBean
        private Pageable pageable;

        @Before
        public void initMocks(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }


        @Test
        public void testListAll() throws Exception {

            // Given
            Page page = new PageImpl(new ArrayList());

            when(itemRepository.findAll(search, pageable)).thenReturn(page);

            // When
            Object obj = ressourceControler.listAll(search, pageable);

            //Then
                    ...
        }
```

Comment: Why is `ResourceController` mock bean? Probably because it is an abstract class, but why are you unit testing an abstract class? Dependencies don't get injected into the mocks.

Comment: @jny - I need unit test this class because some methods has yours own implementations. I would like avoid the use of a child class to do that unit test.

Comment: How `ResourceController` is an abstract class, I can't annotate it with `@InjectMocks` (need to be a real instance) to use `@Mock` and finally inject its dependencies.